# How do I change a section title to include a small note?

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec

I am creating an information document for some animals that I work with at a zoo. The general format that I would like to use is:

```
\subsubsection*{\color{Blue}Animal Name}\textit{scientific name}
information
facts
other stuff
```

Obviously, just putting the scientific name next to the title does not work, but that's how I would like it to work.

I am using subsubsection for the sizing, and the asterisk because I don't want to number them. I also would like to keep my colour change.

I have put some work into researching the \titlesec package, which I believe to be the thing to use, although I haven't managed to workout exactly how to use it in my case. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `\textit`, you might try `\emph`.  (I'm not able to test, so this is a guess.)

Comment: Do you want these listed in a table of contents? It might be more sensible create an `animal` environment instead of using `\subsubsection`.

Comment: I think tilesec would be on possibility, but you also can think of using a custom description environment (with `enumitem`).

Comment: barbarabeeton that is to emphasize a word, not to have it on the same line as a section title.

AlanMunn and Bernard I don't need a TOC, at least right now. All I really want is the extra space on page given by having the scientific name on the same line as the section title.

Comment: "I am creating an information document for some animals that I work with at a zoo." You have animals that can _read_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dedicated environment for this. Something along the following lines should get you started. If you always want an itemized list inside the environment, you could also include that in the environment and just use `\item` inside it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{animal}[2]{\noindent{\bfseries\Large\color{blue}#1}\quad\emph{#2}
\par\nobreak\vspace{\baselineskip}\@afterheading}{\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{animal}{Harlequin duck}{Histrionicus histrionicus}
\begin{itemize}
\item Other common names: painted duck, totem pole duck, rock duck, glacier duck, mountain duck, white-eyed diver, squeaker and blue streak.
\end{itemize}
\end{animal}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

One advantage of this approach is that it's easy to use it to generate a list of the animals in the document if needed. Here's an example of how to do that using the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listanimalname}{List of Animals}
\newlistof{animal}{ani}{\listanimalname}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{animal}[2]{\noindent{\bfseries\Large\color{blue}#1}\quad\emph{#2}%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\baselineskip}\@afterheading
\makeatother
\refstepcounter{animal}
\addcontentsline{ani}{animal}{\protect\numberline{\theanimal.}\quad#1}}{\par}
\setlength{\cftanimalnumwidth}{1em}
\begin{document}
\listofanimal
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{animal}{Harlequin duck}{Histrionicus histrionicus}
\begin{itemize}
\item Other common names: painted duck, totem pole duck, rock duck, glacier duck, mountain duck, white-eyed diver, squeaker and blue streak.
\end{itemize}
\end{animal}

\begin{animal}{Mallard}{Anas platyrhynchos}
\begin{itemize}
\item Found throughout North America, Eurasia and North Africa
\end{itemize}
\end{animal}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of list version]

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Could you perhaps expand on how the newenvironment command works - specifically how perhaps I could edit the title sizing? I am also looking to make the scientific name only italicized. I don't want it the same size and colour as the animal name.

Comment: Why an environment and not a `\newcommand`?

Comment: @Karl I've updated to the answer to show that kind of formatting. You can adjust the formatting anyway you like, really. To limit the scope of the formatting, enclose it in braces.

Comment: @Tommiie The basic idea of latex markup is to create semantic objects and associate formatting to them. Here the contents of the environment are semantically part of the animal description, so it makes sense to have an environment. If I were just using the combination of common name/Latin name in running text, then a macro would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Karl I've updated the code a bit. Please use this version.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, based on a `description` environment?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor} 
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newenvironment{animals}%
    {\begin{description}[font =\color{blue}]}
    {\end{description}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{animals}
        \item[Tasmanian Devil](\emph{Sarcophilus harrissii})\\
        Popularised as a \emph{Looney Tunes} and \emph{Merry Melodies} character by Robert McKimson.
        \item[Dodo] (\emph{Raphus cucullatus})\\
        More Information on this delicious bird in \emph{Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland}.
    \end{animals}

    \end{document}
```

[image]